# Elastic search index lifecycle policy

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, spring-data-elasticsearch

i'm new with elasticsearch
i would like to set index lifecycle policy(from hot to warm), time based
Using java and spring boot to store data.
so my questions are:

1. can i set the lifecycle policy to read from my custom key(of date), if so, how do i do it? does the key needs to be in some format?
2. if 1 is not possible, is there a way to set @timestamp field manually? if we set a key with this format, will it do the trick?
3. if 1 and 2 is not possible, that means that all rollovers should be done programmatically, does anyone have good example? or just use simple select and insert and delete?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am exactly isn't sure what is your question. Anyway, I will try to answer as I understood.

1. life cycle policy can only be based on the date index created that's all.
2. it's index created time only
3. you can create rollover to happen at the hot phase automatically based on time or size or doc count of the index .